# Strip all instances of specific function(s) from C source

Tags: c, bash, awk, sed, strip

## Background

I have a test application that involves libraries from several separate contractors. Each contractor writes a library that utilizes a common logging API which I have already provided. At build time, I can pass a flag which optimizes the logging calls out entirely, as they are pre-processor macros which wrap our underlying `fprintf()` wrapper.

A product requirement change now mandates that two of the contractors can see each others code bases in a limited manner.

---

## The Problem

The logging statements for some of the code the separate contracted teams use has to be purged from code before it is shared between teams, as it may contain intellectual property that we aren't licensed to shared between teams (ie: an explanation of how some obscure algorithm works).

---

## The Question

How can I, on Linux (using `BASh`, `sed`, `VIM`, `awk`, etc), strip all instances of a certain function from source. Some samples:

```
logToClient("Something wrong with process %s (owner = %d).\n", 
    pName, iOwner);
 
logToClientVerbose("Big problem.");
```

I've tried writing a little python script to create a "stack" of all the `(` and `)` characters encountered, but it doesn't work 100% of the time, and I'm hoping there's a simply piece of regex one-liner magic that can accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible for the function to span multiple lines just like normal `printf()` calls.

Comment: There's likely a code "beautifier" out there that you could first run the code through first, standardizing all multi-lines into single lines.

Comment: `The logging statements for some of the code the separate contracted teams use has to be purged from code before it is shared between teams ...` IMHO the *rest of the code* will contain even deeper secrets.

Comment: @wildplasser Not really in this case. Ran it by legal. The code is nothing but a bunch of read/write op-codes.

Comment: `... nothing but a bunch of read/write op-codes ...` And so are the logging function calls. Mybe you just want to restrict their output? ( -> give every party their own logging calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.c
logToClient2("keep this");
logToClient("Something wrong with process %s (owner = %d).\n", pName, iOwner);
logToClientVerbose("Big problem.");
logToClientVerb("Keep Verb.");
```

To delete all references to the two functions that you want deleted:

```
$ grep -vwE 'logToClient|logToClientVerbose' file.c
logToClient2("keep this");
logToClientVerb("Keep Verb.");
```

How it works:

- `-v` tells grep to delete lines that match.
- `-w` tells grep to match only on whole words.
- `-E` tells grep to used extended regular expressions: this is so that we don't have to escape `|`.
- `logToClient|logToClientVerbose` matches either `logToClient` or `logToClientVerbose`.

**Limitation:** This does not parse C.  This only deletes lines with matching words.

### Commands spread over multiple lines

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file2.c
logToClient2("keep this");
logToClient("Something wrong with process %s (owner = %d).\n", 
      pName, iOwner);
logToClientVerbose("Big problem.");
logToClientVerb("Keep Verb.");
```

This awk command divides up the file into records that are marked by a record separator of a semicolon followed by a newline.  It deletes all such records that match one  of the words `logToClient` or `logToClientVerbose`:

```
$ awk '!/\<(logToClient|logToClientVerbose)\>/' RS=';\n' ORS=';\n' file2.c
logToClient2("keep this");
logToClientVerb("Keep Verb.");
```

**Limitation:** This does not parse C.  This only deletes records with matching words.  For example, this will be confused by multiple commands on one line or by lines with spaces after semicolons.

Comment: howAboutThis(logToClientVerbose("Big problem."), saveOuterFunction);

Comment: @JamesBrown What do you think should be done with that line and why?

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I was thinking about removing the inner function (with magic :) but I guess there was no need for that.

Comment: I am able to use `cpp` to force all logging statements to be expanded to fill an entire line. Paired with your solution, it works like a charm!